# Implementation of privacy in blockchain

Tags: bitcoin, privacy

How can we see transactions in a particular block of Bitcoin, if they are encrypted and only Merkle root of transactions is stored on the blockchain. I think in that way we should be having an immutable ledger with private info protected (since we cannot reverse engineer the Merkle root hash to know the transaction info). 
But I've read that blockchain is facing scalability and privacy issues.
Why can't we just encrypt the data in the block and let it be decrypted only with the private key of an individual?

Comment: Hi there. Are you specifically asking for Bitcoin? If so, you'll probably want to ask on their Stack Exchange site: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Comment: no bitcoin was just an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you can do that, but if you process off-chain only. In the same instant you try to read it decrypted, the private key shall be written on the blockchain for ever.

I.e. any

```
decrypt (stored_digest_pointer, private_key)
```

call will remain readable for ever.

Comment: ok but what about merkle tree. isnt merkle tree it self provide encryption to data?

Comment: Merkle tree is the hash of known elements, it can be easily reconstructed starting from the genesis block and traveling forward, it is not a secret information, but a summarizing information, i.e. you can summarize by it the current status, but nobody is able to decrypt it, while all the world is able to validate it as seen before.